# Diamond Shape Java using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
public static void drawNumDiamond(int h) {


    char c= 'A';
    if(h!=0) {
        if (h % 2 == 1) {


            for (int i = h/2; i >= -(h/2); i--) {

                for (int j = 1; j <= Math.abs(i); j++) {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
                for (int j = 0; j <= 2 * ((h/2) - Math.abs(i)); j++) {
                    System.out.print(c);
                }

                System.out.println();
                if (i > 0) {
                    c++;
                } else {
                    c--;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO VALID INPUT");
        }
    }

}
```

It returns diamond shape using chars, the "-" are spaces. Example:
  [drawNumDiamond(9)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUBb9.png)

My question is if it is possible to add "-" on the other side of diamond too by using just max 3 for loops? Something like this:

```
----A----
---BBB---
--CCCCC--
-DDDDDDD-
EEEEEEEEE
-DDDDDDD-
--CCCCC--
---BBB---
----A----
```

instead of:

```
----A
---BBB
--CCCCC
-DDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEE
-DDDDDDD
--CCCCC
---BBB
----A
```

Comment: Just *those* loops?  Obviously not!  Four loops?  Definitely yes!  Just three loops?  Probably yes.  Less?  Maybe just two loops!

Comment: You can do it even using one loop. But what is the point? Such code would be much less readable. Use four loops like Tim showed in his answer.

Comment: @Pshemo I know that, but test wont pass if I write it with 4 for loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HighPerformanceMark mentioned, you can just copy your current `for` loop which prefixes hyphens and add it after printing the letters:

```
for (int i=h/2; i >= -(h/2); i--) {
    StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder("");
    // you only need one loop for the hyphens
    for (int j=1; j <= Math.abs(i); j++) {
        prefix.append("-");
    }
    System.out.print(prefix);
    // and you only need one loop for the letters
    for (int j=0; j <= 2 * ((h/2) - Math.abs(i)); j++) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    // ADD THIS CODE
    System.out.println(prefix);

    if (i > 0) {
        c++;
    } else {
        c--;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawNumDiamond(9);
}
```

Note that we could even generate your output using no loops, but that would leave the code harder to read.

**Output:**

```
----A----
---BBB---
--CCCCC--
-DDDDDDD-
EEEEEEEEE
-DDDDDDD-
--CCCCC--
---BBB---
----A----
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: @asd Updated to use only 3 `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Each line has 3 parts. first part is created from dashes, second part is created from alphabetic characters and third part again is created from dashes. note that second part and third part are the same. you could set first part in a String variable and reuse it for the third part. So you could use only 3 loops.